Optimal solution to minimize the number of questions asked for multiplicity of the first 100 numbers and its expected value
I made a post earlier today asking about the multiplicity of numbers less than 100 and the least amount of "multiple-type" questions asked to guarantee a solution. However, this has sparked a second question based off of that thread, which is shown below:
For reference, the post is below:
Multiplicity of the numbers less than 100
For those of you who did not see the link, the original question was, given two people, one selecting a number between 1 and 100, and the other trying to choose the number, what was the smallest number that guarantee the second person (person B) choosing the number. The question on this thread is based off of this one.
EDIT: It appears the original question is a bit unclear. I have removed the unclear question and will thus make another question to make this clearer.

Question: Given that the number is between 2 and 100, is there a strategy involving asking "is the number a multiple of x" and "Is the number x" questions that minimizes the expected value of the number of questions asked before the second person can determine the value of the number?


"...what is the expected number of..." : depends on what strategy B follows.  In the previous problem, an answer was given that showed a strategy for B that minimized the maximum number of questions that B would have to ask.  Here, as a preliminary step, you must identify the strategy for B that (instead) minimizes the expected number of questions that B would have to ask.

Re my last comment, suppose that partial strategy $~S_1~$ is to automatically ask about $~2,3,5,7,~$ while partial strategy $~S_2~$ is to automatically ask about $~2,3,5,7,11.~$  It is unclear to me, whether the optimal strategy will involve $~S_1, ~S_2,~$ or neither.

@user2661923: Is that strategy optimal? I don't think it was; I think it just got everything done within a maximum of $25$ questions. I admit I may have missed something in reading quickly though.

@BrianTung I agree that the strategy given in the previous answer may or may not minimize the expected number of questions required.

OP: I can't think of an elegant analysis for this. For a maximum of $10$, for example, one optimal approach says ask about divisibility by $2$ first. If "no", then ask about $3$, then ask about either $5$ or $9$ depending on whether the answer to $3$ is "no" or "yes". If "yes" to $2$, then ask about $4$, then ask about either $3$ or $8$ depending on whether the answer to $4$ is "no" or "yes". This identifies the number within $3$ questions unless the number is $2$ or $10$, in which case you must ask about divisibility by $5$ (or $10$). Obviously this isn't unique, but it is optimal.

Anyway, I don't see (but can't assert that one doesn't exist) a strategy for arranging the questions in a tree that is optimally "shallow". I might write some code for the $100$ case.

Not noticing this question, I've edited my answer to the previous question to provide a second strategy that (1) I suspect is an optimal strategy, though I have no proof, and (2) I compute an expected number of guesses for.

Please [edit] and make the title descriptive of the question. Please also include enough information in the post itself.

I realized my question was a bit too vague. Thus, I made a better question that could potentially be answered.
